# Toggle span text on hover over parent div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to toggle the span text of a div when hovering over it.  I want this function to work on numerous divs each with their own text, so I have created an ID for each div but they share the class .square .  I have tried multiple variations, including `$('span",this).toggle` and `$(this).children().toggle();` but nothing seems to be working.  I'm sure there's something small I've missed when translating examples to my own code but can't for the life of me figure out what.  Thanks for any help.

Currently my code looks like this:

HTML

```
<div id="B1" class="square">
    <span class="details">This is square 1</span>
</div>
<div id="B2" class="square">
    <span class="details">This is square 2</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .square{
height:100px;
width:100px;
background-color:#0AA0AB;
color:#FFFFFF;
cursor:pointer;
text-align:center;
margin-left:10px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

jQuery

```
    $('.square').hover(function() {
    $(this).children().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.square').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('.details').toggle();
}, function () {
    $(this).children('.details').toggle();
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2VQF6/)

Comment: Thanks, the fiddle works well and it's working on my local copy as well.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$('span',$(this)).toggle(); // Note the $() around the this
```

But maybe CSS is sufficient (if I understood the problem correctly :) ):

```
.square > span {display:none;}
.square:hover > span {display:inline;}
```

Comment: CSS alone would work but I'm hoping to have a little more flexibility than that.  I like your solution but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Just tell me how flexible you want it to be, I'll try to adapt it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
$('.square').hover(function() {
    $(this).children().toggleClass('square');
});
```